# Hosting a php website on an internal local network

Tags: apache, networking, intranet, localserver

I have four windows PCs  wirelessly connected to a local network and I want to host my PHP website on a server so that all PCs connected to the server can access web applications via an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no much difference between hosting your server on local network or on external server it all come down to the following general steps:

1. Install your webserver e.g. Apache and ensure it has the `php` extension active (default)
2. Make sure that your webserver binds to the correct IP (e.g. 192.168.1.xx or 0.0.0.0 to be accessible from outside the network)
3. Make sure that the firewall (both on the server and client) allows the communication (IP and port)

Answer (score 2):

At first connect the PCs in network using router.

here is diagram

```
                _____________
                |   Router  |  Router IP 10.0.0.2
                |           |
                -------------
                 ;   ;   ;   ;
                ;     ;   ;     ;      
               ;       ;    ;       ;     
              ;        ;      ;         ;   
             ;         ;         ;           ;   
            ;           ;            ;            ;  
           ;             ;              ;                ;   
_____________       _____________      ______________     ___________
|   PC 1    |       |   PC 2    |      |    PC 3    |     | PC 4    |
|           |       |           |      |            |     |         |
-------------       -------------      --------------     -----------
IP 10.0.0.2         IP 10.0.0.3        IP 10.0.0.4         IP 10.0.0.5

Server PC           Client PC          Client PC           Client PC  

This IP should
always be
static
```

**Steps Below**

1. Always use Ethernet connection for server pc to router connection
2. get the MAC address of server PC

**in Router**

1. Login into Server
2. Go to LAN Settings menu add the static IP 10.0.0.2 with server MAC address
3. Go to Port forwarding menu and forward port 80 and 8080 towards IP 10.0.0.2

**in Server PC**

1. Install apache server for PHP hosting
2. Go to httpd.conf file and find the code

   ```
   AllowOverride All

   #
   # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
   #
   # Require all granted
   # onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from ::1
    Allow from localhost
   ```

Add this code below after "`Allow from localhost`"

```
Allow from 10.0.0.2
Allow from 10.0.0.3
Allow from 10.0.0.4
Allow from 10.0.0.5
```

You can increase the client PC and add the IP into the server httpd.conf file

Now it is the time for celebrating

1. Open Client PC Browser
2. Type url http://10.0.0.2/ in browser's address bar and press enter
3. Wait some time
4. Bingo